# Routing files to Laravel app

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I'm running Laravel and using `php -S 0.0.0.0:80` to run my development server. In this situation, *most* requests are routed to my app:

```
/test
/thisRouteToo
/even/with/subdirectories
```

However if the route **could be** a file, it attempts to load the file instead:

```
/css/styles.css
/js/code.js
/this/file/doesnt/exist.txt  -- returns a 404
```

I would like to redirect all such requests to my app if the file doesn't exist. This way one can access `someFile.jpg` and the contents of the JPEG are determined by my app.

I have tried both of the following in my .htaccess file:

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In both cases I get a "404 file not found" when I attempt to access `/someFile.jpg`. The desired behavior would be to follow a route in my app, e.g.:

```
Route::get('someFile.jpg', function(){ return "Test!"; });
```

Comment: Are you sure you enabled `.htaccess` on your dev server? `AllowOverride All` in the apache config. You might also have to enable mod_rewrite in not already.

Comment: This was the issue. I looked into how to set `AllowOverride All` for PHP's built-in web server (I'm running the server with `php -S 0.0.0.0:80`, per the first line of the question) and discovered that PHP's built-in web server ignores .htaccess entirely. It only appeared to work this whole time because they have a white-list of file extensions and unknown extensions are routed to index.php. Apparently you can pass a "router" script to server in place of a .htaccess - which I used to check for file existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @Panama_Jack I was able to look in the right direction for solving this. The trick was:

> I'm running Laravel and using `php -S 0.0.0.0:80` to run my development server

PHP's internal server **does not parse .htaccess files**

It does, however, have some default routing. There's a large list of known extensions (`.js`, `.css`, `.mp3`, etc) - if a request has one of these extensions, it attempts to load a file. If a request does **not** have one of these trusted extensions, it is redirected to `index.php`

However you can instead run the server using the following command: `php -S 0.0.0.0:80 router.php`

This tells it to direct **ALL** requests to `router.php`

I then put the following in `router.php`:

```
<?php

if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )['path']  )) {
    return false;
} else {
    include_once 'index.php';
}
```